# how to set center of far locations in bing map using npm react bing map library

Tags: reactjs

All nodes are visible even though they are geographically located far away. Example: one user in Switzerland & other in India . i am using npm bingmap react library , where i have found center for this , can we pass multiple lat long in this? else can we use setBound method for this? if anyone can provide setbound method in react.

_